# how to write json response of curl command to file

Tags: python, json, api, unix, curl

I was trying to write the result of `curl` to  a file and extracting it and assign it to variable but i was not able to keep getting validations error

```
cmd='curl -k -u admin:admin -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/mixed"--header "Accept:application/json"-F "myPartnm1=@sftprest;type=application/json"-F" myPartname2=@sftppvteopenkey;type=application/json/oc-stream" http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert'

with open("dff.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(os.system(cmd),ident=25)

with open("dff.json") as f1:
    data= json.loads(f1)

print(data['id'])
```

Also attempted with `requests`:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed,
'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
    'myPartnm1': open('sftprest/opt/tr5.txt;type=application/json', 'rb'),
    'myPartname2': open('sftppvteopenkeyopt/tr5/new.pem;type=application/json/oc-stream', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
```

```
{
"massage":"Error validating request",
"validationError":["unable to import cerifecate.Expecting two body parts with certificate info and certificate info and certificate data"]
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `curl` instead of Python's `requests` module?

Comment: `os.system()` doesn't return the output of the command, you have to use `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: You're missing spaces before many of the options to `curl`.

Comment: i was trying to use python requests but it didn't work at all because when try the curl it self it work fine

Comment: Use this site: https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: can you post any answer?

Comment: I'm not going to waste time posting an answer when the whole approach is wrong.

Comment: i did use this converter and apply it many times but it didn't work for me

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: It looks like **nothing** works for you. I wonder why... Post your attempt using `requests` and explain what does not work.

Comment: import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed--header',
}

files = {
    'myPartnm1': open('sftprest/opt/tr5.txt;type=application/json', 'rb'),
    'myPartname2': open('sftppvteopenkeyopt/tr5/new.pem;type=application/json/oc-stream', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

Comment: i just post the python request that i have tried

Comment: The curl code still has the missing-whitespace typos that Barmar pointed out to you earlier. There's no way it works on the command line exactly as given in your Python code.

Comment: Beyond that, show us the specific exception or error you get from the `requests` code (again, _in the question_, not as a comment)

Comment: `multipart/mixed--header` should be `multipart/mixed`. You're getting the wrong conversion because you were missing the spaces before `--header` when you used the curl converter. Start with a `curl` command that works on the command line, then the converter will work.

Comment: yes i have edit it but still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this by using .sh file extension in unix along with path file instead of curl

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space before the -F options

```
json"-F "myPartnm1=@sftp
json" -F "myPartnm1=@sftp
```

Add a space after the -F and remove the space after the double quote.

```
/json"-F" myPa
/json" -F "myPa


curl -k -u admin:admin -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/mixed" --header "Accept:application/json" -F "myPartnm1=@sftprest;type=application/json" -F "myPartname2=@sftppvteopenkey;type=application/json/oc-stream" http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert
```

I used https://curlconverter.com to convert your curl.
It did not convert until I made the above changes.